# XAMPP changed port Failed to connect to phpmyadmin in Windows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

MySQL said: Documentation

**Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

**Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.**

**mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]**

**mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.**

this problem happened when i changed the port to 3308 as default port.

i have tried solution rom previously asked question

```
/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3308';
```

in config.inc.php
note: I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The top two errors **usually** occur when you delete the pwa user from phpmyadmin.

Change this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
```

To:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
```